# Table data disappear after sorting

Tags: nattable

If I sort in nattable, only the first cell in table remains displayed and I get NPE: `at org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.data.ReflectiveColumnPropertyAccessor.getDataValue(ReflectiveColumnPropertyAccessor.java:74)`. All other cells disappear. I guess, problem might be in `composite.setChildLayer(GridRegion.BODY, bodyLayerStack, 0, 1);`. There should be  `sortHeaderLayer` included in `bodyLayerStack` somehow?

In examples is e.g.:

```
ColumnGroupHeaderLayer columnGroupHeaderLayer =
            new ColumnGroupHeaderLayer(sortHeaderLayer, selectionLayer, columnGroupModel);
GridLayer gridLayer =
            new GridLayer(viewportLayer, columnGroupHeaderLayer, rowHeaderLayer, cornerLayer);
NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parent, gridLayer, false);
```

My code:

```
private NatTable createTable(Composite parent, List<TableLine> tLines, String[][] propertyNames,
  PropertyToLabels[] propToLabels, TableParams params, TextMatcherEditor<TableLine>editor) {

BodyLayerStack bodyLayerStack =
    new BodyLayerStack(
            tLines,
            new LineDataProviderColumnAccessor(propertyNames[0].length),
            params.getColumnIndicesForRowHeaders());

DataLayer bodyDataLayer = bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataLayer();

...
IDataProvider columnHeaderDataProvider =
    new DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider(propertyNames[0], propToLabels[0].getPropertyToLabels());
DataLayer columnHeaderDataLayer =
    new DefaultColumnHeaderDataLayer(columnHeaderDataProvider);

ILayer columnHeaderLayer =
    new ColumnHeaderLayer(
        columnHeaderDataLayer,
        bodyLayerStack,
        (SelectionLayer)null);

//
SortHeaderLayer<TableLine> sortHeaderLayer =
        new SortHeaderLayer<>(
                columnHeaderLayer,
                new GlazedListsSortModel<>(
                        bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(),
                        new ReflectiveColumnPropertyAccessor<TableLine>(propertyNames[0]),
                        configRegistry,
                        columnHeaderDataLayer));


CompositeLayer composite = new CompositeLayer(1, 2);
composite.setChildLayer(GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, sortHeaderLayer, 0, 0);
composite.setChildLayer(GridRegion.BODY, bodyLayerStack, 0, 1);

NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parent, composite, false);
//new CustomTextPainter();
new CustomNatTableContentTooltip(natTable);

// before addConfiguration
natTable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
// to sort on a single click
natTable.addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());

natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());
natTable.addConfiguration(new ContextMenuConfiguration(natTable));
natTable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
  
  
});
natTable.configure();

editor.setFilterator(new TextFilterator<TableLine>() {

  @Override
  public void getFilterStrings(List<String> baseList, TableLine element) {
    for( int i = 0; i < element.getLength(); i++ )
      baseList.add("" + element.getObjectByColumn(i));
  }
});
editor.setMode(TextMatcherEditor.REGULAR_EXPRESSION);
bodyLayerStack.getFilterList().setMatcherEditor(editor);

NatTableSelectionProvider.addNatTableData(natTable, bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer(), bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataProvider());

return natTable;
}
```

My solution was to create CustomColumnPropertyAccessor, but it works only for columns with single-row headers:

```
public class CustomColumnPropertyAccessor<R extends TableLine> extends ReflectiveColumnPropertyAccessor<R>
{
public CustomColumnPropertyAccessor(String... propertyNames) 
{
  super(propertyNames);
}

@Override
public Object getDataValue(R rowObj, int columnIndex) 
{
  return ((TableLine) rowObj).getObjectByColumn(columnIndex);
}
}
```

For double-row headers I get: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 1 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)`

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 0):

so I removed index `[0]` from CustomColumnPropertyAccessor for 2row header tables so I get:

```
SortHeaderLayer<TableLine> sortHeaderLayer =
        new SortHeaderLayer<>(
                columnHeaderLayer,
                new GlazedListsSortModel<>(
                        bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(),
                        new CustomColumnPropertyAccessor<>(propertyNames),
                        configRegistry,
                        columnHeaderDataLayer));
```

Sorting works for tables with double headers as well. But still, it is strange it does not work without this CustomColumnPropertyAccessor, as in examples. Maybe because I do not use grid.